# why gulp and grunt installing globally is recommended

Tags: npm, gulp

Why gulp/grunt are recommend to be installed globally?

Can I just put them in package.json as other packages?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this works is because gulp tries to run your `gulpfile.js` using your locally installed version of gulp.

Essentially, when you install gulp locally the script isn't in your `PATH` and so you can't just type gulp and expect the shell to find the command. By installing it globally the gulp script gets into your `PATH` because the global `node/bin/` directory is most likely on your path.

To respect your local dependencies though, gulp will use your locally installed version of itself to run the `gulpfile.js`.